# Malayalam font characters saving into the mysql database as unknown characters

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, mysqli

When I try to insert a utf8 charcter into my mysql web server database (table is also having collation: utf8_general_ci) unknown junk characters are inserted into the db. I'm trying to input this name (**ടോണി**) in malayalam language into mysql db  using an html file and when this value is submitted on the text box and send to the server db, it appears as like this: (**à´Ÿàµ‹à´£à´¿**). I have also added this line in my php file:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci'",$con);
```

but still no use. The name is in malayalam. But what I get from db is unknown language. How is that happening?? I will show you my php files and html files:

**insert.php**

```
<?php   
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","db_name"); 
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)) 
{ 
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error(); 
} 
$txt= $_POST['ta']; // get the unicode text from a submit action. 
$unicodeText = $txt; 
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci'",$con);
$cQry= "insert into doc_test (unicodeText) values ('".$unicodeText."')" ; 
if(!mysqli_query($con,$cQry))
{
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "1 record added";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

This is my html file:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />  
</head>
<body>

<form action="insert.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="ta">
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

when i run this on my server and enter a value in malayalam in the textbox, and press the submit button, the value will be inserted into the mysql db, but it is not the one which I had entered in the textbox. Also there is a warning shown after the value is entered in the db. It is shown below:

```
PHP Error Message

Warning: mysql_query(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in /home/a6001661/public_html/malayalam/insert.php on line 9

1 record added
```

What is the possible reason for this warning?? Can someone please correct me out. Also suggest the ideas to enter the value in the correct font malayalam in db. Thanks in advance...

Comment: You're mixing MySQL APIs, they do **not** mix. Change to `mysqli_query` and move your connection variable at the beginning.

Comment: Use this `mysqli_query($con,"SET NAMES 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci'");`

Comment: He means that not all function names that start with `mysql` are from the same extension. Just look them up in the manual and you'll see they're filed under different chapters.

Comment: I know that i should use mysqli_real_escape_string for validating/ escaping the string. But I have done this way to make it simple.

Comment: Side note: With Malayalam you are going to run into deep trouble if you are not going to use prepared statements.

Comment: *"then should I use mysqli everywhere in my program, since mysql is deprecated?"* - Yes, but not just that, again, see my [`first comment`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24939185/malayalam-font-characters-saving-into-the-mysql-database-as-unknown-characters#comment38755975_24939185).

Comment: I strongly recommend you don't use `mysqli_real_escape_string()`. It's very verbose and error prone. Use prepared statements when possible.

Comment: Use [**`mysqli_*` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO**](http://php.net/pdo) with [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements). That is what you should use.

Comment: Did you not try `mysqli_query($con,"SET NAMES 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci'");` instead of `mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci'",$con);`?

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) after your opening `<?php` tag: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: Also, try placing `$con->set_charset("utf8");` right before your query.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Success...The warning has been removed and the value is now properly entering into the mysql db..Thanks for your help...

Comment: @TeeJay Actually, I would prefer if I did, for future readers who may happen to fall upon your question.

Comment: While trying to display the same enterd data, There is also this problem of unknown characters...

Comment: Also, make sure everything in your MySQL database uses UTF-8. See this: http://cameronyule.com/2008/07/configuring-mysql-to-use-utf-8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've decided to make my comment as an answer, for possible future readers and to close the question.

---

Try placing `$con->set_charset("utf8");` right before your query.

That is one method that has worked for many here on SO, where a similar problem was faced.

Also, add error reporting to the top of your file(s) after your opening `<?php` tag:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

---

***Sidenote:*** You are presently mixing MySQL APIs using `mysql_query()`.

It does not mix with `mysqli_*` functions inside the same code.
It would need to be `mysqli_query()`

---

**Edit:**

*"Success.. Adding `<meta charset="utf-8">` solved my problem"*

as per comments below.

Comment: <?php   
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","db_name"); 
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)) 
{ 
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error(); 
} 
$con->set_charset("utf8");

$cresult = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT unicodeText FROM doc_test"); 
while ($crow = mysqli_fetch_array($cresult,MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
{ 
echo ( $crow['unicodeText']); 
} 
mysqli_close($con);
?>

Comment: This gives the output like this:

à´ªà´¿.à´µà´¿ à´ªàµ‹à´³àµâ€à´Žà´‚.à´±àµà´±à´¿. à´œàµ‹à´¸à´«àµâ€Œà´Ÿàµ‹à´£à´¿à´Ÿàµ‹à´£à´¿ à´œàµ‡à´•àµà´•à´¬àµà´¬àµ

Comment: Is your file saved as UTF-8 and without BOM (byte order mark)? @TeeJay

Comment: This is my php file to read the entered utf8 values from mysql db and display it on browser... But still when i run this code, unknown characters are displaying on my browser instead of malayalam characters... Please suggest me the errors in it...

Comment: you mean the php file to view the data from mysql db??

Comment: When you save a file, there are a few options to save them as. I use Notepad++ and not the Windows plain Notepad to save file with. The extra options available are ANSI, UTF-8 (with, or without BOM). @TeeJay this could make a big difference.

Comment: I'm also using notepad++ for editing... But I didn't find any extra options in it while saving a file...

Comment: @TeeJay Under the "Encoding" dropdown menu option, you will see "Encode in..." and "Convert to...", choose "Convert to UTF-8", then either with the BOM, or without the BOM. Then, just do save.

Comment: @TeeJay Also have a look at this page on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through there are other possible answers in there you can look into. One of which being to add `<meta charset="utf-8">` inside the `<head></head>` of your document.

Comment: Did you also add `mysqli_query($con,"SET NAMES 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci'");` as I suggested too? @TeeJay and [`my comment`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24939185/malayalam-font-characters-saving-into-the-mysql-database-as-unknown-characters/24940647#comment38759584_24940647) above it.

Comment: @TeeJay That is great news! Sometimes, the simplest of things solve big problems :-) Very glad to hear it, *cheers* You're very much welcome, always glad to help out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57941/discussion-between-tee-jay-and-fred-ii).

Answer (score 1):

You can get this in three simple steps.

1. simply set column Collation to "utf8_general_ci" in your database
2. header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
   in your file.

and

1. $mysqli->set_charset("utf8"); this after mysql connect query.

thats all.

Comment: Thanks. This answer worked perfectly. I also added <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">